# can't click btn-group in Bootstrap row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <div class="btn-group pull-left">
      <a class="btn btn-default" href="/servers">
First
</a>
      <a class="btn btn-default" href="/servers?page=4">
Prev
</a>
      <a class="btn btn-default" href="/servers">
1
</a>
      <a class="btn btn-default" href="/servers?page=2">
2
</a>
      <a class="btn btn-default" href="/servers?page=3">
3
</a>
      <a class="btn btn-default" href="/servers?page=4">
4
</a>
      <a class="btn btn-default disabled">
5
</a>
      <a class="btn btn-default" href="/servers?page=6">
6
</a>
      <a class="btn btn-default" href="/servers?page=7">
7
</a>
      <a class="btn btn-default" href="/servers?page=8">
8
</a>
      <a class="btn btn-default" href="/servers?page=9">
9
</a>
      <a class="btn btn-default disabled">
…
</a>
      <a class="btn btn-default" href="/servers?page=6">
Next
</a>
      <a class="btn btn-default" href="/servers?page=12">
Last
</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Source seems like above.
They are in row class and col-md-9.

When they are full-sized, they are clickable.

[image]

While they are mobile-sized, I can't click some of them.

[image]

I think the reason is row.
How can I make them to be clickable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this under the code. Or it may be better to use bootstrap pagination class.

`<div class="clearfix"></div>`